# groovy get warnings from withBatch statement

Tags: jdbc, groovy

I need to get SQLWarnings from batch records that might fail. But the statement closes automatically, so I'm not sure how to get that data. Basically I wanna do this.

```
    sql.withBatch(sqlCommand) { stmt ->
        stmt.addBatch(map)
}

SQLWarning warning stmt.delegate.getWarnings()
while(....) println warning.getMessage()
```

The issue is that even if I capture the statement from within the closure, it is still closing at the end of the with batch. Is there any idiomatically groovy way to do this? Or should I just try to do it the java way?

Comment: Can you post some actual code showing your problem?

Comment: @tim_yates I am not sure what more I can show you. The question boils down to, given a sql.withBatch command, is there any way to extract SQLWarnings?

Comment: @tim_yates that's my actual batch command, the bottom part doesn't work because it doesn't know about the stmt object

Comment: Why not extract the messages inside the batch, and add them to a list defined outside the batch?

Comment: The messages wouldn't be available until the batch executes (when the closure ends)